# pipe operator not behaving as expected RXJS

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Please look at my component below the purpose to is to listen on changes to an input, which it does and then emit the value to the parent component. I created a pipe to only emit every so often and therby minimize the calls to the api, for some reason even though I can see through various `console.log` statements that it goes in the pipe, it emits the value on every change. What is it that I am missing:

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output, KeyValueDiffers, DoCheck, KeyValueDiffer} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable, of} from "rxjs";
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map, skip, switchMap, takeUntil, tap} from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'core-ui-typeahead-filter',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  templateUrl: './typeahead-filter.component.html',
})
export class TypeaheadFilterComponent implements DoCheck {
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() caption: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() cssClass: string;
  @Input() cssStyle: string;
  @Input() function: any;

  @Input() data: Observable<string[]>;
  differ: any;
  detectChange: string = '';
  // term$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  text$ = new Observable<string>();

  @Output() onTypeahead: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();


  constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
    this.differ = this.differs.find({}).create();
  }

  handleTypeahead = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
    text$.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(500),
    ).subscribe((value) => {
      this.onTypeahead.emit(of(value))
    })


handleSelectItem(item) {
  this.onSelect.emit(item);
}

ngDoCheck() {
    const change = this.differ.diff(this);
    if (change) {
      change.forEachChangedItem(item => {
        if (item.key === 'detectChange'){
          console.log('item changed', item)
          this.text$ = of(item.currentValue);
          this.handleTypeahead(this.text$);
        }
      });
    }
  }

}
```

More background: There is an ngModel on the input linked to `detectChange` when it changes then the `ngDoCheck` is called and executes. Everything is done in observables so in the parent I can subscribe to the incoming events.
EDIT -------------------------------------------------------------------
Tried the following solution based on my understanding of @ggradnig answer, sadly it skips over my pipe something seems wrong with it, really not sure what:

```
 handleTypeahead = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    this.test.subscribe(this.text$);
    this.test.pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      debounceTime(500),
      // switchMap(value => text$)
    ).subscribe((value) => {
      tap(console.log('im inside the subscription',value))
      this.onTypeahead.emit(value)
    })
  }



handleSelectItem(item) {
  this.onSelect.emit(item);
}

ngDoCheck() {
    const change = this.differ.diff(this);
    if (change) {
      change.forEachChangedItem(item => {
        if (item.key === 'detectChange'){
          console.log('item changed', item)
          this.text$ = of(item.currentValue);
          this.handleTypeahead(this.test);
        }
      });
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You are creating a new observable on every change with `of` in `ngDoCheck`. This way, `debounceTime` won't work (a new scheduler is created for every change). Instead, create a subject and subscribe once to this subject with the `debounceTime` pipe. Notify the subject in `ngDoCheck`.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate further how this would look? I think I understand what you are saying but am not sure how to write the code.

Comment: Also unclear about what you mean by "subscribe once to this subject" don't subjects subscribe to observables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following -

```
export class TypeaheadFilterComponent implements DoCheck {
  @Input() id: string;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() caption: string;
  @Input() placeholder: string;
  @Input() cssClass: string;
  @Input() cssStyle: string;
  @Input() function: any;

  @Input() data: Observable<string[]>;
  differ: any;
  detectChange: string = '';
  // term$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  text$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  serachTerm$: Observable<string>;

  @Output() onTypeahead: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  @Output() onSelect: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();


  constructor(private differs: KeyValueDiffers) {
    this.differ = this.differs.find({}).create();
  }

  // handleTypeahead = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
  //   text$.pipe(
  //     distinctUntilChanged(),
  //     debounceTime(500),
  //   ).subscribe((value) => {
  //     this.onTypeahead.emit(of(value))
  //   })

  ngOnInit() {

    this.serachTerm$ = this.text$
                           .pipe(
                            distinctUntilChanged(),
                            debounceTime(500),
                            //filter(), //use filter operator if your logic wants to ignore certain string like empty/null
                            tap(s => this.onTypeahead.emit(s))
                           );
  } 

handleSelectItem(item) {
  this.onSelect.emit(item);
}

ngDoCheck() {
    const change = this.differ.diff(this);
    if (change) {
      change.forEachChangedItem(item => {
        if (item.key === 'detectChange'){
          console.log('item changed', item)
          this.text$.next(item.currentValue);          
        }
      });
    }
  }

}
```

Now, at the bottom of your template put the following line -

```
<ng-container *ngIf="searchTerm$ | async"></ng-container>
```

Having this line will keep your component code free form managing the subscription [i.e. need not to subscribe/unsubscribe]; async pipe will take care of it.

Comment: You either should `switchMap` to `text$` to `serachTerm$` or, subscribe to it. It does not seem to me that `serachTerm$` would be used in the template along with async pipe.

Comment: @Akxe switchMap is needed to cancel the previous typeahead search but it is business logic driven but it's not mandatory. I forgot to format the code for the template change. See the edited code above. It will work now.

Comment: The container does the job now. Yet i would suggest to remove ngOnInit as the pipe can be initialized immediately

Comment: searchTerm$ observable needs to be initialized. It can be done in the constructor or ngOnInit. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Thanks so much! My remaining issue is I do not fully understand this, what does it mean to write this `this.serachTerm$ = this.text$...` are we saying that the Observable now becomes a behaviour subject? Is that the same as subscribing?

Comment: @user2216584 I just wanted to say that having ngOnInit explicitly for it is unnecessary

Comment: @Michael With this.searchTerm$ = this.text$... I am setting up an observable which could be used in the template - <ng-container *ngIf="searchTerm$ | async"></ng-container>. Using async pipe takes care of subscribing and unsubscribe [on destroy] automatically. You can also do this.text$.sibscibe() also but, in that case, you will have to unsubscribe the subscription. See the following - https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0